# android thread worker queue

Tags: android, multithreading, queue

I have some threads that runs in my app, I want that if this threads are called at the same time they are not execute concurrent. And I also want to wait 1 second delay between run the next thread. How can i do that?

Maybe the right way is to implement a worker queue of runnables but which Object i have to use to do that and how? ThreadPoolExecutor is a good choice?

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use an IntentService. It implements a background thread, and automatically queues start requests. You start it like any other Service, with startService(intent).
Documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html
This way you also ensure that your background threads are allowed to finish, even when the ui-thread is sent to the back by the system or the user.